# What is x-irdeto-edge-indiv response from AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-headers, google-chrome-devtools, response

Can someone please explain what is x-irdeto-edge-indiv response header? i get this from AWS cloudfront servers. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like added by Cloudfront, they generally have x-amz , this may have been added by origin

Comment: Hi @JamesDean, thanks for the reply. Do you have any idea what does that mean? What effect will custom response header has on a browser ? Thanks.